# How can I make the navigation bar to show only at the very top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

How can I make the navigation bar re-appear only when the users scrolls at the very top? currently, the nav bar appears when the users scrolls up, irrelevant the position of the screen.

Html

```
<header class="nav-down">
 <div> navigation </div>
</header>
```

Javascript

```
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('#navigation-container').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
var st = $(this).scrollTop();

// Make sure they scroll more than delta
if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

// If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
// This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
    // Scroll Down
    $('header').removeClass('navigation-container').addClass('nav-up');
} else {
    // Scroll Up
    if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
        $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
    }
}

lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

CSS

```
header {
height: 40px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
width: 100%;
z-index: 999;
padding-top: 50px;
}

.nav-up {
top: -70px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether i'm misunderstanding your question or not, but if you want the navigation bar to only be at the top, you'll have to either remove `position: fixed` from the header's css, or make it so that the navigation div is outside of the header div.

Comment: Thank you @msafi. It worked! I changed the position form fixed to absolute.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to do in order to achieve that:

1. Delete / comment the entire navbar script.
2. Cleanup the `header` declaration in `CSS` by removing all but the following 2 lines:

```css
header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}
```